# Generate 1000 independent random variables with normal distribution

Tags: python

I have some problems about this question. Generate 1000 independent random variables with normal distribution N(9,10) and plot the result in a histogram.
For the histogram use the intervals with length 1,namely[-1,0),[0,1),[1,2)...etc

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def demo1():
    mu ,sigma = 9, 10
    sampleNo = 1000
    s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, sampleNo)
    plt.hist(s, bins=100, density=True)
    plt.show()

demo1()
```

I wonder how to choose bins number and I don't know how to adjust intervals with length 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed a sequence to the `bins` argument. For example, if you give `bins = np.arange(100)` the histogram will have 100 bins of length 1 going as [0,1),[1,2)...

Another example, you can write `plt.hist(s, bins=np.linspace(-50,50,100), density=True)` which would plot the histogram of range (-50,50) with bin length 1